# Changing bash home position makes it run slowly. Any fix?

Tags: bash, console, escaping

I'm having some trouble with bash. I'm changing my console's home position so I can reserve some rows in the top of the screen to print the current status of the script, and allow all the standard output to scroll in the lower part of the screen. This way, the upper lines showing the status doesn't get removed when the screen scrolls down.

I'm doing this by using these lines to do so, where `<RNUM>` is the number of rows I need to freeze.

```
 \033[<RNUM>;r
 \033[<RNUM>;1H
```

It works, however the console performance is highly lowered, it print lines really slowly (say it takes 4 times more to print the same amount of lines it usually prints).

Does anyone have a fix for the performance issue? Am I using the correct codes? I wasn't able to find any information about this stuff on the net, and I don't recall where I got these codes years ago.

Comment: This isn't so much a `bash` issue as it is a virtual terminal issue.   Are you using `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` or `konsole` or one of the many others?  Try terminals and see if it makes a difference.